# function with parameter

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, functions

Tell me, please, am I right about the following statement?

Specifically interested in the consequence of the limit

$\lim_{a \rightarrow b} |\alpha_k-\alpha_{k+1}|=|\beta_k-\beta_{k+1}|$

what
$|\alpha_k-\alpha_{k+1}|\ne 0$ even if $|\beta_k-\beta_{k+1}|=0$

If $|\beta_k-\beta_{k+1}|\ne 0$ is almost no doubt, but if for some $|\beta_k-\beta_{k+1}|=0$?

**Is it true that the sequence that tends to zero the zero does not contain?**

**Statement**

Consider a function of a real variable with a parameter that has an infinite number of zeros
$\{f(a,x)\}$ and the function does not turn into an identical zero under any $a$ (1)

if there is a limit
$\lim_{a\rightarrow b} f(a,x)=f(b,x) $ (2)

then when $a\ne b$ all zeros are real (no compex or even zeros).

**Proof**

Let $\alpha_k$ zeros of the function  $f(a,x)$ when $ a\ne b $ (3)

and $\beta_k$ zeros of the function  $f(b,x)$ (4)

then obviously the limit of (2) follows the other two limit

$ \lim_{a \rightarrow b} \alpha_k=\beta_k $ (5)

$\lim_{a\rightarrow b} |\alpha_k-\alpha_{k+1}|=|\beta_k-\beta_{k+1}|$ (6)

it is obvious from the last limit that
$|\alpha_k-\alpha_{k+1}|\ne 0$ (7)

where $\alpha_k$ and $\alpha_{k+1}$ any two adjacent zero of the function  $f(a,x)$ when $a\ne b$

Is that right?

**Or (7) does not follow from (6), then why?**

everything above is really wrong

It is enough that from all the parameter values it was possible to choose such a countable number of values that different functions with these parameter values formed the basis of the Hilbert space, i.e. they were linearly independent.

There are other details, about this property is the most important.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're asking, but the set of zeros of a function doesn't necessarily vary continuously with respect to a parameter. Consider $f_a(x)=a\sin x$ or $f_a(x)=\sin x+ae^x$ as $a\to 0$.

Comment: here is key factor that limit (2) is exists $\lim_{a\rightarrow b} f(a,x)=f(b,x) $

Comment: Do those limits not exist in my examples?

Comment: 1) $a\sin x\ne \sin x$ 2) both function have to have infinite number of zeros with any $a$

Comment: I don't follow. $\lim_{a\to0}(a\sin x)=(0\sin x)=0$. And both of my examples have infinitely many zeroes regardless of the value of $a$.

Comment: $\lim_{a\rightarrow b} f(a,x)=f(b,x) $ here $a$ and $b$ iz not zero, if $b$ is zero it was $\lim_{a\rightarrow 0} f(a,x)=f(0,x) $, here $f(0,x)$ is part of the sequence

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There's nothing special about zero as a parameter value. How about $\lim_{a\to1}(a-1)\sin x$?

Comment: ok, statement is not enough, I will think about how to improve it